# Mustache-Java: How to get value in Map by key

Tags: java, mustache

I am using JMustache in Java.

I have Map variable in my Mustache template. How can I fetch a value at a particular key in the map, as we do in Java (map.get()).

I know how to iterate through keys and values of a Map in a template. But I want a solution without iteration so that I can evaluate an expression such as:

### Data

```
{
    "cities": [
        {
            "Tokyo": {
                "overview": {
                    "population": "19000000",
                    "area": "450000"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sydney": {
                "overview": {
                    "population": "4500000",
                    "area": "6250000"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

### Template

```
"The population of Tokyo is: {{cities['Tokyo'].overview.population}}"
```

Comment: Do you have to use JMustache? You can do it in one line using for example the Jackson library.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is an issue with your mustache syntax. `cities['Tokyo']` is not valid. `cities` is an array. You can iterate over an array, but not select an element based on its key value (or any other condition for that matter).

So this JSON object fits better:

```
{
    "cities": {
        "Tokyo": {
            "overview": {
                "population": "19000000",
                "area": "450000"
            }
        },
        "Sydney": {
            "overview": {
                "population": "4500000",
                "area": "6250000"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second, you have to parse the JSON `String` to a structure using `Map` and `List` objects. Most JSON parsers are able to do this. In this example, I use [noggit](http://yonik.github.io/noggit/).

```
@Test
public void testSO_45787572() throws IOException {
    final String json = 
        "{\n" +
        "   \"cities\": {\n" +
        "       \"Tokyo\": {\n" +
        "           \"overview\": {\n" +
        "               \"population\": \"19000000\",\n" +
        "               \"area\": \"450000\"\n" +
        "           }\n" +
        "       },\n" +
        "       \"Sydney\": {\n" +
        "           \"overview\": {\n" +
        "               \"population\": \"4500000\",\n" +
        "               \"area\": \"6250000\"\n" +
        "           }\n" +
        "       }\n" +
        "   }\n" +
        "}";
    assertEquals("The population of Tokyo is: 19000000", Mustache.compiler()
        .compile(new StringReader("The population of Tokyo is: {{cities.Tokyo.overview.population}}"))
        .execute(new ObjectBuilder(new JSONParser(json)).getObject())
    );
}
```