# How to display nested json object in json array on Server side using Mustache

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-boot, mustache

I am using mustache to create template using Spring-boot-starter-mustache on Server side to create templates.

I referred : https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-mustache/

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I have a Java JSON object that I am creating in my Controller:

```
model.put("schoolJson", schoolJson);
return "viewJson";
```

JSON structure:

```
{
"school": "abc",
"loc":  "def",
"type": [
            {
            "section": "sec1",
            "test": {
                    "grade": "gradea"
                    }
            },{
            "section": "sec2",
            "test": {
                    "grade": "gradeb"
                    }
            }
        ]
}
```

In my viewJson I want to display the 'grade' of each 'test' in 'type'. But it does not get displayed. Can someone help out here.

```
<div>
 <p>{{schoolJson.school}}</p>

  {{#schoolJson.type}}
   <ul>
    <li>schoolJson.type.grade</li>
   </ul>
  {{/schoolJson.type}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `li` should be done this way:

```
<li>
    {{#test}}
        {{grade}}
    {{/test}}
</li>
```

This is because you have to go into the context of the nested `test` object to be able to get the `grade` value

Comment: still does not work. This way it works when I do a client side scripting using mustache. But this does not work on Server side HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

If the "test" key is always present, you can just write:

```
<li>{{test.grade}}</li>
```

I just checked and this works as intended. If it is not working server side in your code, the question is: how do you parse the JSON String? JMustache itself is not JSON-aware, you have to parse it to a data structure which is understood by jmustache. See this example for using noggit and JMustache together: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47485363/868941